# How to get an authorization code via HTTP request for Google OAuth 2.0 Playground - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, oauth2-playground

I need some help with Google OAuth 2.0 Playground, I hope someone can help.
I wonder how to to get an authorization code via HTTP request for Google OAuth 2.0 Playground via python? Is it possible?
I'm trying to get an authorization code doing this request :

[image: get]

And I was trying to forward the authorization code expected with this post :
[image: post]

My main code:

```
auth_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
access_token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
callback_url = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"

client_id = 'xxx'
client_secret = xxx'

authorization_redirect_url = auth_url + '?response_type=code&client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + callback_url + '&scope=openid'
authorization_code = requests.get(authorization_redirect_url)

data = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': authorization_code, 'redirect_uri': callback_url}
access_token_response = requests.post(access_token_url, data=data, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, auth=(client_id, client_secret))
```

If I try to run my code I get :

```
response:
{'Date': 'Wed, 18 Aug 2021 23:35:42 GMT', 'Expires': 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Server': 'scaffolding on HTTPServer2', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
body: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Malformed auth code."
}
```

Any advice ?

Kind regards,
Juliano

Comment: To get the code, you need to launch a webserver to respond to the redirect_url callback. I wrote an article that explains the process in curl including a special python web server to respond to the OAuth callback: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley , I'm going to read your article. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if I'm missing your intent; it's unclear why you want to automate the flow using the OAuth Playground.

If you're trying to automate the OAuth flow for any of Google's services, I encourage you to use Google's (Python) SDKs rather than hand-roll your own auth code.

For example, see the OAuth flow documented [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) for (the) Gmail service.

A strength of Google's APIs is that there's one for **every** Google service and, once you are familiar with the mechanism for one service, you can apply the principles to every service.

Comment: Hello Daz, thank you :) I'm doing this flow via OAuth playground because I was told to do that. That's how this project that I'm working for has its authentication layer running. It's probably a bad solution, we are trying to figure out a better way I will try to use Google's (Python) SDKs as you suggested. Thank you :)

Comment: I made it, I can now get a token via Google's (Python) SDKs . But, when I try to execute my code in the google cloud platform, it starts requiring my user account. How do I set an authentication ? Thank you

Comment: Great! The example I referenced shows how you'd apply those credentials to Gmail. You should be able to use that as a template for the service(s) that you're using.

Comment: Hi Daz, it's annoying the consent screen popping up every time that I need to run my code, is there a way to avoid that ? Thanks :)

Comment: If you followed the Gmail example, you should only be prompted by the consent screen *if* your credentials are not persisted locally. After running once, the credentials (including access and refresh tokens) should be persisted locally and you should not need be prompted by the consent screen until the credentials become invalidated.

Comment: Morning Daz, I have a question, Is it possible to automate my code using something like Control M, Cloud Composer etc ?
I need now to do that, but unfortunately I have, in the first execution, the necessity to consent the first execution, so is there a way to do that ? 
Thank you :)

Comment: If you're authenticating as a User account, you must always initially approve the consent screen. If you're software running some process on behalf of a User account then you should consider using a Service Account. You can delegate auth to a service account: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation Please consider opening new questions rather than adding comments on previously answered questions.